# Phonon modes in one-dimensional monoatomic chain

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons

I am familirazing myself with the lattice dynamics reading Ashkroft-Mermin (p2 ch 22). 
My question is what it the mathematics behind the deriviation

$U^{harm}=1/2 K \sum_{n} [u(na)-u([n+1]a)]^2$ (22.22)

$\frac{\delta U^{harm}}{\delta u(na)}=-K[2u(na)-u([n-1]a)-u([n+1]a)]$ (22.23)

I feel  like it is very basic and I fail to see it or I totally misunderstand the notation. ( I get something like $-K(u(na)-u[(n+1)a]$).

How it comes, that one of the displacements is for (n-1)a atom? Is the 22.23 has this form to fit the concept of this lattice to be a system of balls connected by spring?

Comment: $u(na)$ appears in two terms in $U^\text{harm}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when you vary your first equation that you use a different index instead of $n$.  Do the following:

$$\frac{\delta U^{harm}}{\delta u(ma)}$$

this gives

$$
\frac{1}{2}K \sum_{n} 2 [u(na) - u([n+1]a)]\left[\frac{\delta u(na)}{\delta u(ma)} - \frac{\delta u([n+1]a)}{\delta u(ma)} \right]
$$
by the chain rule.  But
$$
\frac{\delta u(na)}{\delta u(ma)} = \delta_{n,m} \text{ and } \frac{\delta u([n+1]a)}{\delta u(ma)} = \delta_{n+1,m}
$$
Now we have four terms:
\begin{equation}
K\sum_{n}[u(na)\delta_{n,m} - u(na)\delta_{n+1,m} - u([n+1]a)\delta_{n,m} + u([n+1]a)\delta_{n+1,m}]
\end{equation}
and performing the sum for each term forces $n$ to take on the necessary values.  This gives
$$
K[u(ma) - u([m-1]a) - u([m+1]a) + u(ma)] = K[2u(ma) - u([m-1]a) - u([m+1]a)]
$$